# Prometheus - send a list of metrics to Gauge

Tags: go, metrics, prometheus

I have a list of metrics in json format to be send to prometheus.How would I use Guage metrics type in client_golang to send these metrics to prometheus all at once?

Right now I have below code

```
var (
      dockerVer = prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Name: "docker_version_latency",
            Help: "Latency of docker version command.",
      }))
func init() {
    // Metrics have to be registered to be exposed:
    prometheus.MustRegister(dockerVer)
}

func main() {

    for {
        get_json_response(1234,"version")
        dockerVer.Set(jsonData[0].Latency)

        // The Handler function provides a default handler to expose    metrics
        // via an HTTP server. "/metrics" is the usual endpoint for that.

        http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
    }
```

}

I have many more metrics and I have to read these from the json and send it to gauge dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to write a custom collector as part of an exporter, see https://github.com/prometheus/consul_exporter/blob/master/consul_exporter.go#L156 as one example.

Docker also has Prometheus metrics built in that can be enabled, so you may not need to write this.